# When using file-loader and html-loader in webpack the src attr of image is '[object Module]'

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

I am doing a project with webpack4 from scratch. But when I try to display an image in an HTML file, I face a weird problem:
After `npm run build`, the src of image tag is built as `<image src="[object Module]"`.
The HTML part is:

`<img src="images/main_background.jpg">`

The `webpack.config.js` is this :

```
   // ignore ...
   {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
       {loader: 'html-loader'}
    ]
   },
   {
      test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/,
      use: [
        'file-loader'
      ]
  }
```

And the version of these two loaders:

```
"file-loader": "^5.0.2",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
```

I can't figure out what the issue is...

Comment: How are you trying to display the image in the HTML file?

Comment: Sorry. i am gonna update my question.And im doing like this :
<img src="./static/images/demo.png">

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding `esModule: false` option to file-loader like so:

```
  ...
  {
    test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/,
    use: [
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        esModule: false
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
```

Same applies to url-loader.

esModule option has been introduced in file-loader in version 4.3.0 and in 5.0.0 it has been set to true by default which can be a breaking change.

Sources:

- [file-loader release history](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/releases)
- [relevant github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/338)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been losing my mind trying to figure out why the other answers would not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[name][hash].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'images',
        esModule: false,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're lazy, you can manually access the image path from that `Module` object by way of the `default` property:

```js
const imgPath = require('path/to/img.jpg').default;
```

That'll give you the image's exact path after it's been prepped for distribution, eg:

```
/images/logo-192.png?88bf116f524693c599897adae2bb688b
```

If you're using a framework like Vue, you can just pop it straight into the src attribute:

```html
<img :src="require('path/to/img.jpg').default">
```