# How do I fix [Object Module] in image src of webpack output?

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

I'm trying to set up a modern vanilla web starter with Webpack.

I got stuck when I added `webpack-html-loader` and `html-loader`. Here's what happens...

1. When I make use of an `img` tag in the entry `index.html` file, with an `src` attribute like this (`./imgs/image.png`), the `src` attribute in the `dist` folder is replaced with `[object Module]`. But when I remove the dot before the `uri` (`./imgs/image.png` to `/imgs/image.png`), the `src` output in the `dist` folder is exactly the same as that of the `src`. This doesn't reference the image I want to include.
2. Since the `src` value of the webpack output is exactly the same as the source, I try to be crude and use the `uri` to the image in the output folder like so `/dist/img/image.png`. This works, but it's not a great experience. I would love to use a `uri` to my image in the `src` folder and have webpack replace it with `dist` at build time. Is this possible?

Here's what my file structure looks like after `npm run build`

```
- dist
  - imgs
    - image.png
  - index.html
  - main.js
- node_modules
- src
  - index.html
  - imgs
    - image.png
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- webpack.config.js
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "imgs",
              publicPath: "imgs",
              name: "[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.html")
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I made a repo of it [here](https://github.com/vickOnRails/vanilla)

Thanks a lot for your time

**Update** (02-01-2020)

Someone in the comment pointed out a solution to the problem. ([When i using file-loader and html-loader in webpack. The src attr of image gonna be like '[object Module]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114479/when-i-using-file-loader-and-html-loader-in-webpack-the-src-attr-of-image-gonna/59115624#59115624))

The solution is to set the `esModules` object to `false` in the `file-loader` rule like so

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        // Here!!!
        esModule: false,
        outputPath: "images",
        publicPath: "images",
        name: "[name].[ext]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When i using file-loader and html-loader in webpack. The src attr of image gonna be like '\[object Module\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114479/when-i-using-file-loader-and-html-loader-in-webpack-the-src-attr-of-image-gonna)

Answer (score 4):

Please, take a look at this post:

[When i using file-loader and html-loader in webpack. The src attr of image gonna be like '[object Module]'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115624/6640504)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve [object module] error through 'default' property:
require('../../images/svg-1.svg').default

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the default value of what you are trying to import.
for exemple :
instead of doing this :

```
const mySVG = require('./path/to/svg');
```

do this

```
const mySVG = require('./path/to/svg').default;
```